# properties.getProperty(key) method returns null value

Tags: java, swing, jakarta-ee, properties-file

I am load the properties file and get the value from that file but when i using **"Properties"** class and **getProperty(key)** method, it was return **null** value.

code:

```
public class LoadPropertiesFile {

public static String getProperty (String key, String filePath) {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    String value = null;
    try {
        String appHome = ConfigUtil.getApplicationHome() + filePath; 
        inputStream = new FileInputStream(appHome);

        //load a properties file
        properties.load(inputStream);

        //get the property value 
        System.out.println(properties.getProperty("7"));   //print **Unlock**
        System.err.println(key);   //print **7**
        System.out.println(value);   //print **null**
        value = properties.getProperty(key);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (inputStream != null) {
            try {
                inputStream.close();
            } catch(IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return value;
}
}
```

Output:

```
Unlock
7 
null
```

Property File:

```
2=Interactive
3=Network
4=Batch
5=Service
7=Unlock
8=Network Cleartext
10=Remote Desktop
11=Logon with cached credentials
```

call method:

```
logonType = new LoadPropertiesFile().getProperty("7", "path");
```

When i call that method it will return **null** value only. please help me guys.

Comment: What would you expect `int i; System.out.println(i); i = 5;` to print? (Don't try it; guess)

Comment: @immibis I think you wanted to say *to print 5, not just to print ;)

Comment: @1337 it's a question. "What would you expect <code> to do?"

Comment: @immibis Did you edit it? O_o I swear it there was no "What" before... ;)

Answer (score 3):

You are initalizing value with null.

```
String value = null;
```

And you assign it **after** printing it:

```
System.out.println(value);
value = properties.getProperty(key);
```

**Output:** `null`

So value can only be null when you print it, as you never change its value until `System.out.println(value);`.
Just switch those two statements:

```
value = properties.getProperty(key);
System.out.println(value);
```

**Output:** `unlock`

**Edit**

properties.getProperty(key) may return null too, but only if there is no such key in its table, otherwise it will return the assigned value, in your example `unlock`.

See the API Documentation on this for more details:

> **public String getProperty(String key)**
>
> Searches for the property with the specified key in this property list. If the key is not found in
> this property list, the default property list, and its defaults,
> recursively, are then checked. The method returns null if the property
> is not found.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#getProperty(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println(value);   //print **null**
value = properties.getProperty(key);
```

Switch these two lines and initialize `value` ***before*** printing it:

```
value = properties.getProperty(key);
System.out.println(value);   //print Unlock
```

Comment: will this method return `null`?

Comment: @user32118114 properties.getProperty(key) will return null if there is no such key, but in that case it will return "unlock".

Comment: @user3218114 It will return null if(and only if) the key does not exist.

Comment: @BackSlash what your answer says.

Comment: as per the output method should not return null value.

Comment: @user3218114 I'm not getting the point. Can you be a little more clear?

Comment: `value = properties.getProperty(key);` will initialize the value and the returned value will never be null. What OP's last line says : When i call that method it will return null value only

Comment: @user3218114 Are you sure? What will happen if the key doesn't exist? `value` will be `null`.

Comment: @BackSlash Look what key is passed as argument and what is output.

Comment: @user3218114 Please, look at the code. `System.out.println(value);` is **before** `value` gets initialized, so it will print out `null`. It's what my answer states, and it's why the OP is getting `null`.

Comment: @BackSlash `System.out.println(properties.getProperty("7"));` what it is printing? `key="7"` passes. and `value = properties.getProperty(key);`

Comment: @user3218114 `System.out.println(value); value = properties.getProperty(key);` Do you see something wrong here? Let me show you something similar [in this demo](http://ideone.com/D3d19W), maybe you'll get the point

Comment: OK but I was more concerned about last statement. *When i call that method it will return null value only.* The method will not return `null` value, Am I right?

Comment: @user3218114 I really think that the OP is wrong. It can't happen with the scenario he described, it's ***impossible***. If the file exists and holds that content, everything will work just fine.